# "Being beaten to it by a week"?

Tags: phrases, colloquialisms, speech, listening

I was watching this: [video 0:26](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D87jIKFTYt0&t=26s), and got lost about what he was saying. Roughly, what I heard was: "Another criterion is that it should be something that few other people are doing, because there are few things worse than working five years on a problem **being beaten to it by a week by somebody else.**" And this was what YouTube autogenerated as subtitles as well.

But it does not make sense to me. Could someone tell me if I heard it wrong or "being beaten to it by a week"/"being beaten to it" is a phrase?

Comment: You can look up the idiom 'beat someone to it' at say [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/beat_someone_to_it). What 'it' is doesn't need to have been stated, but must be deducible from context.  'Being beaten to it by a week' means that somone got to the goal you were both pursuing a week before you would have done.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah my bad, I should have checked the dict first. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've heard right, although the indefinite article is important, and it appears to be missing in your question title ("by week" vs "by a week").

In this case "it" is the solution of the problem, and someone has beaten you to that solution, i.e. solved the problem first, and the amount of time they've beaten you *by* is "a week", which just means that you were a week away from solving it when they found the solution.